# Figure caption indent problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, indentation

The last lines of my `figure` captions are indented too much or centered. I use `floatrow` package which usually doesn't conflict with LaTeX. Is it possible to fix this?

My preambles are as follows:

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up,indention=.5cm,labelsep=period,justification=centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}    
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
```

Comment: Minimal example, please: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: With "with the TeX package" you mean LaTeX itself, don't you?

Comment: @Martin, yes LaTeX

Comment: @BrettHarry: Guess what the option `justification=centerlast` does.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: @lockstep, @Caramdir Thanks! I got it! I removed `justification=centerlast` from `\usepackage[...,justification=centerlast,...]{caption}

Comment: @lockstep: please write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `justification=centerlast` option from the `caption` package.